# Can someone briefly explain php backward compatibility?

Tags: php, mysql, version, compatibility

I coded my website's php/mysql about 15 years ago and pretty much forgot about it. Now I need to fix a problem caused by unescaped apostrophes. I popped mysql_real_escape_string() into the code and it seems to work fine, but the manual says "This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0." My shared hosting server is running PHP 7.1.33 so I don't understand what this means. If mysql_real_escape_string() was removed from PHP 7.0.0, why does it work for me? For that matter, why hasn't my whole site with its 15-year old code come to crashing down long ago?

Comment: I'd add a test page to output `phpinfo()` on the server. I'd want to double-check the version of PHP it's running. Despite what your hosting provider told you it's running, it might not be on the specific old host you run your site on. Or they may have found a way to add the obsolete mysql extension to a PHP 7.1 host. The phpinfo output should show you the extensions loaded to confirm that.

Comment: You might be after prepared statements. These handle escaping characters in queries.

Comment: Well, what do you know. phpinfo() says it's actually PHP 5.6.40.

Comment: Just so you know, even PHP 7.1 last received security updates nearly 3 years ago, so I hope that's not the *newest* version the host is offering you. https://www.php.net/eol.php